# How to share and update array of objects between 2 components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I wonder if anyone can help?

I have a list of base users that I fetch from an API and render to the page via the `Dashboard` component.

I want to create another list, in a separate route/component (`Favorites`), that allows for a user to create a personalized user list, like a list of favorites.

At the moment, I am stuck on what to now do with the array of favorites. How do I get the array sharable from Dashboard to Favorites? Could I create a context? But how would that look?

Below is my dashboard component that contains the base list and the favorites.

A sandbox is https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-frost-8zuzw1?file=/src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js:304-370 for anyone interested

```
 const Dashboard = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  const { data: usersData } = useFetchUsers();

  const onClickHandlerAdd = (user) => {
    setFavourites([...favourites, user]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("/myList");
        }}
      >
        Navigate To My List
      </button>
      {usersData?.map((user) => (
        <>
          <div key={user.id}>
            <p>{user.id} </p>
            <p>{user.name}</p>
            <button onClick={() => onClickHandlerAdd(user)}>Add</button>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
      Another List
      {favourites?.map((user) => (
        <>
          <div key={user.id}>
            <p>{user.id} </p>
            <p>{user.name}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Lifting state up or using [context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) should do the job, check [sharing states](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)

Comment: How would I do it with context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a context in `App.js` with `createContext`, create the state and pass it into your components with the `Provider` of your context like so:

```
export const FavContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);

  return (
    <FavContext.Provider value={{ favourites, setFavourites }}>
      <HashRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={"/"} element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path={"/favorites"} element={<Favorites />} />
        </Routes>
      </HashRouter>
    </FavContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now you can access the objects passed into the components by importing the context and extract them using `useContext`:

```
import { FavContext } from "../../App";

const Favorites = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { favourites } = useContext(FavContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("/");
        }}
      >
        Navigate To Dashboard
      </button>
      {favourites?.map((user) => (
        <>
          <div key={user.id}>
            <p>{user.id} </p>
            <p>{user.name}</p>
          </div>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit black-rain-q9p5fn]

Comment: I wondered if you knew why my onClickHandlerDelete is not returning the modified array. Do I need to provide a call back function to update the context? SB here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-surf-sqgo0q?file=/src/components/Favorites/Favorites.js:251-271